# WinForm Browser Control Which Element was right clicked?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have 3 context menus for my WinForms Browser control.

BrowserImages, BrowserLinks, and BrowserDefault.

1. Default is loaded when a blank area of the document is right clicked
   on
2. Links is displayed when a link is right clicked on
3. and Images is displayed when - you guessed - an Image is right clicked on.

When the DocumentCompleted is fired I add the Document_ContextMenuShowing Event - the code for that is:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Displays the Correct Context Menu for the element that is being right clicked on
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">
    /// HTMLDocument: The content of the web browser when the right click was detected.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="e">
    /// HtmlElementEventArgs: Used for getting the location of the mouse so we know where to display the Context Menu
    /// </param>
    void Document_ContextMenuShowing(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        var res = (HtmlDocument)sender;

        if (res.ActiveElement.InnerHtml.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("img"))
        {
            cmsBrowserImages.Show(e.ClientMousePosition.X, e.ClientMousePosition.Y);
        }
        else if (res.ActiveElement.InnerHtml.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("href"))
        {
            cmsBrowserLinks.Show(e.ClientMousePosition.X, e.ClientMousePosition.Y);
        }
        else
        {
            cmsBrowserDefault.Show(e.ClientMousePosition.X, e.ClientMousePosition.Y);
        }
    }
```

Is there a better, more robust (better working) way to do this?
C# code preferred but VB.Net will beok to, easy enough to rewrite.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [document.elementFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465795.aspx) rather than rely upon `document.activeElement`.